# Ansible Playbook executes only first role from the list of roles

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a simple playbook named nimb_job.yml.

```
 ---
 # file: hosts_nimb
 - hosts: hosts_nimb   
   roles:
     - apache-httpd
     - tomcat
```

In the roles directory I have two subdirectories named apache-httpd and tomcat with main.yml file in tasks subdirectory for each of them.

main.yml in `roles/apache-httpd/tasks/`

```
---
# file: roles/apache-httpd/tasks/main.yml
- name: Check Apache httpd status
  shell: apachectl status
```

main.yml in `roles/tomcat/tasks/`

```
---
# file: roles/tomcat/tasks/main.yml
- name: Check tomcat status
  shell: systemctl status tomcat
```

Once I run playbook named nimb_job.yml through AWX GUI this executes only the first role apache-httpd and never the second.

When I switched direction in the list of roles in playbook so in first place was tomcat, the tomcat role is executing only and never the second.
I do not see anything in the output window after first role is executed.

I'm a little confused and suspect some configuration issue. I'm using Ansible 2.4.1.0 in Docker.

Comment: Can you edit your question, so the formatting of 'nimb_job.yml' matches what is actually in nimb_job.yml? Formatting is important in YAML, so possible something to do with that. Hard to know tho with the broken formatting in your question.

Comment: i used simple ping instead of shell in  roles/apache-httpd/tasks/main.yml and now it is possible executing next role. It is strange because during apachectl status I got FAILED even if standard out shows proper results (I mean status of apachectl). So looks like when first role return FATAL the next one will not be executed.

Comment: If you are getting failures add the actual output you see to your question. If a task fails, the play will abort, hence later roles not running. There is nothing obviously wrong with your code. My best guess is that Ansible needs to switch to root to run those commands. You will need to ensure that the user Ansible uses to connect to your host has full sudo access, then you can add `become: yes` between the `hosts` & `roles` lines. This will cause Ansible to attempt to use `sudo` to become root, before running those commands.